# Put authentication/login configuration inside PROJECT

Tags: java, jboss

I implemented a custom login module I want to use with the JBoss AS 6. I followed some tutorial guidelines on the internet, namely http://x-techteam.blogspot.com/2007/04/jboss-custom-login-module-simple.html.

They write about configuring ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/login-config.xml and deploy a JAR with the custom login module, but I don't like the idea of changing a configuration within the JBoss folder.

I really would like to have ALL configurations within my WAR file. The EE application I write will be sent to some customers and they should not have to worry about configuring some security contexts or roles via XML.

So my question is:
Can I have a local login-config.xml within my war that will be picked up by JBoss?
Can the custom login module class remain within my war, without having to deploy it to some JBoss folder?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic security domains:
[link](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Dynamic_Security_Domains.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I searched for.